# Sending Object + Message via websocket when database is modified

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, websocket, spring-data-jpa

I'm using hibernate and JpaRepository + PostgreSQL. I have the following code which listens to any modifications made to the database.

```
public class PermitEntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Permit target) {
        perform(target, INSERTED);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Permit target) {
        perform(target, UPDATED);
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(Permit target) {
        perform(target, DELETED);
    }

    @Transactional(MANDATORY)
    private void perform(Permit target, Action action) {
        EntityManager entityManager = BeanUtil.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        entityManager.persist(new PermitHistory(target, action));
        //Send permitHistory to client via websocket to update changes
        PermitUpdates updates = new PermitUpdates();
        updates.sendUpdatedPermit(new PermitHistory(target, action));
    }
}
```

In the method perform, it is where changes made would be updated into a new table. At this point, i wish to also send this "PermitHistory" back to the user via a web socket. This is so that when the user is modifying/viewing the table, on the client side he will be able to receive a prompt that new changes have been made to the fields so he can choose to refresh to display the updates.

Edit: I created a new class "PermitUpdates"

```
public class PermitUpdates {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public void sendUpdatedPermit(PermitHistory permitHistory) {
        if (permitHistory != null) {
            this.template.convertAndSend("/changes", permitHistory);
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a WebSocketConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/changes");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

With this a new error occured:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.historical.websoc.PermitUpdates.sendUpdatedPermit(PermitUpdates.java:19)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you can create your STOMP message service and share

Comment: With reference to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207513/sending-message-to-client-periodically-via-spring-web-socket, so do i simply call the method "greeting()" from within my "perform" method? Correct me if i am wrong as i am still trying to understand how all these works.

Comment: Yes you can try "greeting()" method, STOMP messaging send to connected clients

Comment: I updated my question, not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: 'PermitUpdates updates = new PermitUpdates();' take as singleton (Use @Autowire) then try.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking such a silly question, i tried but it says annotation type not applicable.. How do you autowire this?

Comment: If you meant PermitUpdates should be a singleton class, i modified it but still the same: "PermitUpdates.getInstance().sendUpdatedPermit(new PermitHistory(target, action));"